# What does PROPERTY_OFFLOAD_SUPPORTED mean?

Tags: wear-os, watch-face-api

`WatchFaceService` has a method `public void onPropertiesChanged(Bundle properties)` which returns a bundle of properties. One of them has a key `PROPERTY_OFFLOAD_SUPPORTED`.

Here are all properties that are available in WatchFaceService:

```
public static final String PROPERTY_BURN_IN_PROTECTION = "burn_in_protection";
public static final String PROPERTY_LOW_BIT_AMBIENT = "low_bit_ambient"; 
public static final String PROPERTY_IN_RETAIL_MODE = "in_retail_mode"; 
public static final String PROPERTY_OFFLOAD_SUPPORTED = "offload_supported";
public static final String PROPERTY_PHYSICAL_HANDS = "physical_hands";
```

They are not there in the docs but can be accessed from Android Studio.

What does `PROPERTY_OFFLOAD_SUPPORTED` property represent, and how it should be used?

Comment: Where are you seeing this? There's no mention of it at https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/watchface/WatchFaceService.Engine.html#onPropertiesChanged(android.os.Bundle), nor anywhere else on that page.

Comment: Yeah right, it doesn't exist on the internet. I see it inside `WatchFaceService.class` in Android Studio. These are all properties that are there:

`public static final String PROPERTY_BURN_IN_PROTECTION = "burn_in_protection";
public static final String PROPERTY_LOW_BIT_AMBIENT = "low_bit_ambient";
public static final String PROPERTY_IN_RETAIL_MODE = "in_retail_mode";
public static final String PROPERTY_OFFLOAD_SUPPORTED = "offload_supported";
public static final String PROPERTY_PHYSICAL_HANDS = "physical_hands";`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include these crucial details.

Answer (score 1):

`PROPERTY_OFFLOAD_SUPPORTED` is related to `WatchFaceDecomposition`. This is a feature that's available on certain devices (built on the Qualcomm 3100 platform), where the ambient mode drawing of the watch face is handed over to a separate (very energy-efficient) piece of hardware.

There are a lot of restrictions for what you can and can't do in this mode. It also offers a few new opportunities such as more color options and having a second hand(!).

The feature is unfortunately not very well-documented but there are a few articles out there that talk about how to build watch faces that supports it:

1. http://turndapage.com/2018/12/07/implementing-the-new-ambient-second-hand-for-wear-os-with-watch-face-decompositions
2. https://www.programmersought.com/article/49454594831/